# XML not being passed to WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm running some local test on a API, for some reason the data XML data is not making it to the API. rData.labelDetail is submitted to the API as null.

It almost appears as though I'm using the incorrect ContentType but I've tried application/xml and text/xml with no success.

Request:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public partial class TestAPI : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:56146/Packages.svc/auth");
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><RequestData xmlns='http://www.labels.com/label'><details>Test|Second Part</details></RequestData>";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace XYZService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IPackages" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPackages
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "auth")]
        ResponseData Auth(RequestData rData);
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace XYZService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Packages" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Packages.svc or Packages.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Packages : IPackages
    {
        #region

        public ResponseData Auth(RequestData rData)
        {
            var data = rData.labelDetail.Split('|'); //Keep getting error here
            var response = new ResponseData
            {
                Name = data[0],
                PackageID = data[1]
            };

            return response;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.labels.com/label")]
    public class RequestData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string labelDetail { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ResponseData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string PackageID { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not put your `Stream`, `WebResponse`, and `StreamReader` into `using` blocks and see what happens?

Comment: Hi John, I've tried to implement the using and webresponse returning an error. Do you have samples of how to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an element name mismatch.  In your XML request, your root element  `RequestData` has a nested element named `details`:

```
    string postData = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><RequestData xmlns='http://www.labels.com/label'><details>Test|Second Part</details></RequestData>";
```

But in your data contract, the corresponding property is named `labelDetail`:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.labels.com/label")]
public class RequestData
{
    [DataMember] // Notice that "Name" is not set
    public string labelDetail { get; set; }
}
```

You need to make the names match, for instance by doing:

```
    [DataMember(Name="details")] 
    public string labelDetail { get; set; }
```